# iText7でPDFを生成する際に“Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.”の例外が発生する

Tags: java, pdf

私はiText7でpdfを生成する際に、下記の事が発生しています。

```java
com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Pdf indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current pdf document.
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:195) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:185) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:115) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:187) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:115) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:187) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:115) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.writeToBody(PdfWriter.java:383) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.flushObject(PdfWriter.java:289) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.flushObject(PdfDocument.java:1572) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.flush(PdfObject.java:159) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.flush(PdfObject.java:127) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObjectWrapper.flush(PdfObjectWrapper.java:94) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.flush(PdfPage.java:495) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.flush(PdfPage.java:454) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:785) ~[kernel-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.close(Document.java:120) ~[layout-7.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.xcz.afbp.thirdparty.service.impl.GeneratePDFService.generatePDF(GeneratePDFService.java:160) ~[classes/:na]
```

私が生成するコード

```
public void generatePDF(CreditQueryData creditQueryData, Map<String, UserCreditContentView> contentViewMap, List<PackageCreditContentView> needRetrievedCreditContentList, File pdfFile, BigDecimal score) throws Exception {

    if (!pdfFile.exists()) {
        boolean x = pdfFile.createNewFile();
        if (!x) {
            LOG.error("生成文件出错" + pdfFile.getPath());
            return;
        }
    }

    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(pdfFile)));
    Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4);
    document.setRenderer(new DocumentRenderer(document));

    pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new WatermarkingEventHandler());

    try {
        //operate code just add tableA tableB tableC...

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.info();
    } finally {
        document.close(); //exception throws here
    }


}
```

iText7での私のスタイルコードは、

```java
 private PdfFont bfChinese = null;
```

サービスコンストラクタで呼び出されます。
フォントを`static`で設定しようとしましたが、動作しませんでした。 これはplace throw例外です。

```
private void write(PdfIndirectReference indirectReference) {
    if (document != null && !indirectReference.getDocument().equals(document)) {
        throw new PdfException(PdfException.PdfIndirectObjectBelongsToOtherPdfDocument);
    }
    if (indirectReference.getRefersTo() == null) {
        write(PdfNull.PDF_NULL);
    } else if (indirectReference.getGenNumber() == 0) {
        writeInteger(indirectReference.getObjNumber()).
                writeBytes(endIndirectWithZeroGenNr);
    } else {
        writeInteger(indirectReference.getObjNumber()).
                writeSpace().
                writeInteger(indirectReference.getGenNumber()).
                writeBytes(endIndirect);
    }
}
```

つまり、2つの異なるドキュメントがあることを意味しますが、別のドキュメントをいつ作成したか分かりません。

Answer (score 1):

特定の`PdfFont`インスタンスは、1つのドキュメントに対してのみ使用できます。 `PdfFont`インスタンスを使用すると直ぐに、そのドキュメントにリンクされ、別のドキュメントでこれを使用することはできなくなります

例えば、

```js
class ThisGoesWrong {

    protected PdfFont font;

    public ThisGoesWrong() {
        font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(...);
    }

    public void createPdf() {
        ...
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("test").setFont(font);
        document.add(p);
        ...
    }
}
```

最初の`createPdf（）`を呼び出すときに`ThisGoesWrong`クラスが正しいPDFを作成しますが、2回目に呼び出すときは例外が表示されます。

この問題は以下のように解決できます。

```
class ThisWorksOK {

    public ThisWorksOK() {
    }

    public void createPdf() {
        ...
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(...);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("test").setFont(font);
        document.add(p);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

他のサードパーティーツールを利用して、例えばコンポーネントでPDFなどのドキュメントを作成することが実現できます。

使用するツール：[Spire.PDF for .NET](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/download-pdf-for-net-now.html)

詳細なコード：

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
PdfPageBase page = newDoc.Pages.Add();
string message = "Hello world!";
PdfFont font = new PdfFont(PdfFontFamily.Helvetica, 13f);
PdfBrush brush = PdfBrushes.Red;
PointF location = new PointF(20, 20);
```

こうすることで無事にPDFドキュメントを作成できます。